# How to use m/d/Y date format Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am using Laravel 5.6 and i need to add birthday with m/d/Y format but get date error. Example for this value '09-20-2018'.

The birthday is not a valid date.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'birthday' => 'required|date|date_format:m-d-Y',
    ];
}
```

Comment: From the docs: `You should use either date or  date_format when validating a field, not both.` That's probably causing the error.

Comment: Why are you using `date_format:m-d-Y` when you want `m/d/Y`?

Comment: Though the example date fits the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'birthday' => 'date_format:m/d/Y|required|date',
    ];
}
```